# Почему бот вконтакте отправляет много ответов за раз?

Tags: python, django, вконтакте, бот

Первый раз в жизни пишу бота для группы вк и столкнулся с проблемой - в ответ на мое сообщение, бот бесконечно шлет мне ответы. Такой вопрос уже здесь задавали, но про php. Насколько я понял, дело там было в том, что нужно обязательно слать строку "ок" в ответ. Я вроде бы так и делаю.

Пока никаких проверок у меня нет, на любой входящий запрос бот должен присылать одно сообщение:

```py
def send_message(msg, user_id):
    random_id = random.randint(1, 2147483647)
    extra_params = {'user_id': user_id, 'group_id': GROUP_ID, 'message': msg, 'random_id': random_id}
    r = requests.get(SEND_MESSAGE_URL, params=dict(**BASE_REQUEST_PARAMS, **extra_params))
    return r


class MainRouterView(View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MainRouterView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def post(self, request):
        r = send_message('тестовый ответ', TEST_USER_ID)
        return HttpResponse('ok', content_type="text/plain")
```

Comment: А сервер точно успешно отвечает ok? В логах статус 200, размер ответа 2 байта и так далее?

Comment: @andreymal `"POST /api/v1.0/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "curl/7.52.1"` В какой-то момент он стал давать по одному ответу, а потом внезапно вывалил штук 30. И я теперь не понимаю то ли лимиты исчерпались, то ли все починилось по непонятным причинам. А HttpResponse он же строку возвращает по-умолчанию? Я content_type от безысходности добавил)